# iCalendar to force the 'Accept/Decline' buttons to appear in an updated event instance for Outlook?

Tags: outlook-2007, icalendar

Does anyone know what iCalendar conditions I need to force the 'Accept/Decline' buttons to appear in an updated meeting message for Outlook 2007?   Is there a combination of regular iCalendar fields, or some X-MICROSOFT fields I'm missing out on to force a re-accept?  Our updates come far enough after the initial message to make a re-accept mandatory.

I see this note for Outlook 2007, and I'm hoping that some combination of values will force an 'Accept/Decline' - short of a change of value in DTSTART.

> "If changes are made to meeting
>   details, attendees receive
>   an update with the changes
>   highlighted, rather than having
>   to reaccept the meeting."
>
> --http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100743061033.aspx

This problem occurs for updates to single, non-recurring, UID only meetings as well updates to recurring meetings using RECURRENCE-ID and UID.

We use the ATTENDEE line in the update such as:

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;
   CN="Full Name":MAILTO:user@domain.com
```

to attempt to force the Accept/Decline behavior.

Thank you everyone!

ICAL messages are below.

I needed to place the ATTENDEE records in the initial message to please Notes, but tested without those lines to the same effect.   I also tried sending the initlal message as METHOD:PUBLISH and the updates as METHOD:REQUEST.   The records update, but no new Accept button is offered in Outlook 2007.   We bump the SEQUENCE number for each update.

*INITIAL MESSAGE*

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//Product/Platform/Name//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ical_event+5088@ical.server.org
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20091129T000000Z;BYDAY=SA
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20091114T180000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20091114T190000
SUMMARY:Sub Test 7
ORGANIZER;CN="'Meeting'":MAILTO:ical_event+5088@ical.server.org
DTSTAMP:20091027T212241Z
STATUS:TENTATIVE
SEQUENCE:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="Full 
 Name":MAILTO:user@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="Full 
 Name":MAILTO:user2@domain.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

*UPDATE MESSAGE*

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//Product/Platform/Name//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ical_event+5088@ical.server.org
RECURRENCE-ID:20091114T230000Z
DTSTART:20091114T230000Z
DTEND:20091115T000000Z
PRIORITY:5
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Sub Test 7
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:Access Code XXXXXXX
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:Sub Test 7
ORGANIZER;CN="'Meeting'":MAILTO:ical_event+5088@ical.server.org
DTSTAMP:20091027T222122Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20091027T221822Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:7
URL:http://ical.server.org/calendar/detail.shtml?event
 _id=5088&instance_id=5385&recurrence_id=20091114T230000Z
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="Full 
 Name":MAILTO:user@domain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="Full 
 Name":MAILTO:user2@domain.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Outlook will ask for Accept/Decline when the event time is changed. I don't know how to force it otherwise. My hack would be to change the time of a second.

Answer (score 5):

To force Outlook to show Accept/Decline buttons again you must change one of the following:

- DTSTART
- DTEND
- Recurrence

See [this very thorough article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/outlooking/archive/2012/06/11/understanding-meeting-updates.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Mentioned link on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160426160216/http://blogs.technet.com/b/outlooking/archive/2012/06/11/understanding-meeting-updates.aspx 

Updated(?) in the client developer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/about-meeting-requests-as-informational-updates-and-full-updates